# Skipping a class hierarchy level in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

In a Java EE 7 application, I have a class hierarchy that basically follows the Composite pattern. The classes are listed below. Each one has an `@Entity` annotation. The inheritance strategy, annotated at `Base`, is `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)`.

- Base
- AbstractContainer (`extends Base`)
- ConcreteContainer1 (`extends AbstractContainer`)
- ConcreteContainer2 (`extends AbstractContainer`)
- Item (`extends Base`)

Now, AbstractContainer adds behaviour, but not fields. Thus, it's table only has a single column with the id, which is totally redundant. Can I make JPA skip this table?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to make AbstractContainer a @MappedSuperclass.

> Mapped superclass inheritance allows inheritance to be used in the
>   object model, when it does not exist in the data model. It is similar
>   to table per class inheritance, but does not allow querying,
>   persisting, or relationships to the superclass. Its main purpose is to
>   allow mappings information to be inherited by its subclasses.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Mapped_Superclasses

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that. It fails as some classes refer to it (Composite pattern...). I may need to change that as well <sigh>.